# Bernoulli Equation Application - Water Spray into the air & Siphoning Gasoline out

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

The following images show the application of the Bernoulli Equation in a variety of cases.

First, spraying water into the air. State 1 is where water exits the hose; State 2 is where the water jet reaches the air. The relationship between State 1 and 2 can be expressed using the equation below the diagram.
[image: Water Spray]
$P_n$ states the pressure at point $n$; $V_n$ states the velocity of the fluid at point $n$. $z_n$ states the vertical potential (height) at point $n$.

One thing that I wasn't able to understand is how $V_1^2/2g$ and $V_2^2/2g$ result in a value of zero. Doesn't the fluid at both states 1 and 2 have a particular velocity, which can't be zero?

[image: Fuel Tank]
Second, siphoning out gasoline from a fuel tank. State 1 is where gasoline is static in a fuel tank; State 2 is where siphoned gasoline is filled inside the gas can. State 3 is where the siphoned gasoline goes through the hose; reaching maximum height. The relationship between State 1 and 2 (relationship A) is expressed above the diagram; the relationship between State 2 and 3 (relationship B) is stated below the diagram.

From relationship B, $V_2^2/2g$ and $V_3^2/2g$ gets eliminated, probably because both are holding identical values. But why? As acceleration due to gravity exists, shouldn't it be obvious for $V_2$ and $V_3$ to have different values?

Any advice or comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example the term $V_1$ with is not zero. However, it is approximated very small compared to the other terms. You can see the reasoning below in your figure: $V_1^2 \ll V_j^2$. In other words, the jet velocity is so much higher then the velocity in the hose, that we can contribute the jet velocity, and hence the height, dominantly to the pressure drop.

For the second example, realize that the reference point are on the surface, and not right at the entry of the hose (I mean, that would make life more complicated). Because the diameter of the tank is so much bigger than the diameter of the hose, you can also neglect these term (i.e., it would work for infinitely large tanks, where the liquid level doesn't drop.